# Textbox keyListener in Java

Tags: java, actionlistener

so I have this part of my code (I cannot post everything because it's just too long and so far this is the only problem with it). Our professor assigned us to make our own Assembler just like MARIE and we are having a trouble with these lines of code:

```
 else if(get.charAt(0)=='B')//input
                 {                                                

                     inputfield.setEditable(true);
                     //INSERT LISTENER HERE!
                     AC.setText(inputfield.getText());
                     System.out.println(""+col);

                     //insert action here - HALP

                 }
```

The entire thing gets a value from a table sort of like an Instruction in Hex and if the Intruction starts with B like B000 then it will toggle the input textbox which is named inputfield. It works fine but we need to add a key listener in the part where it says //INSERT LISTENER HERE! for when the user will press enter the AC.setText(inputfield.getText()); will be executed. How should we do it? I mean we tried actionListener but it sort of stops the loop unless another button is clicked. We need another way that when the user presses enter it automatically resumes the execution.

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

Add action listener to textfield. ActionEvent will occur when you press Enter while editing in textfield.

```
    JTextField field = new JTextField();
    field.addActionListener(new ActionListener() {
        public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
            // action to perform when one hits "Enter"
        }
    });
```

Comment: Does this answers your question?

Comment: It works but it doens't automatically resume the original loop :( Like we have to click the run button again to resume it. Like the action lister paused it or something.

Comment: Then there is issue in code. To handle Enter press event on text field, I have posted tip in my answer.